# Framework mobile para desenvolvimento em Cordova

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache-cordova, mobile, framework

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação híbrida que é utilizado o Cordova e necessito de soluções para a parte gráfica do APP. Em princípio penso em utilizar o Bootstrap, mas como tenho pouco conhecimento no desenvolvimento mobile, gostaria de indicações sobre quais os framework's mobile que estão sendo utilizados atualmente.

Comment: Talvez ajude: http://www.totalcross.com/blog/top-5-frameworks-para-desenvolvimento-de-apps-em-html5-e-javascript/

Comment: Eu particularmente recomendaria o ionic visto que além de usar o cordova ele é preparado para PWA e possui uma documentação bem vasta,  mas existe o https://framework7.io/ da uma olhada nele.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já viu o [IONIC](https://ionicframework.com) ? O desenvolvimento dele é em Angular 2 e 4 e compilado com Cordova, com isso ele tem TAG's próprias no HTML.

Caso queira apenas um framework de design, pode tentar dar uma olhada no [MaterializeCSS](https://materializecss.com/).

Outros:
[Material Design for Boostrap](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/) 
[Material Design Lite (MDL)](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#badges-section)

Comment: Sim, meu foco é apenas para design. Já ouvi falar a respeito do MaterializeCSS, mas seria melhor que o Bootstrap?

Comment: Eu acho o Materialize mais 'bonito' e mais Mobile, mas vai de cada um, há também frameworks do Boostrap com aparência Material Design, há também o Material Design for Boostrap. Editarei a resposta para colocar mais.